# Can't figure out well why my function is returning True with anagrams

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my function (says if 2 compared words are anagrams or not):

```
def are_anagrams(word1, word2):
    word1list = list(word1)
    word2list = list(word2)
    anagramfalse = False
    anagramtrue = True
    if (word1 == word2):
        return anagramfalse
    if (word1list.sort()) == (word2list.sort()):
        return anagramtrue
    else:
        return anagramfalse
```

So this function is returning

```
are_anagrams("lopped", "poodle")
```

as `True`, for some reason. Can't figure out why. It should be compared the sorted list of letters for each word and returning a `False`.

Solution? Mainly just want to know what's wrong.

Comment: Clue:  what does `list.sort()` return?  You need to use the `sorted()` built-in instead.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` does not do what you think.  Observe:

```
>>> x = list('lopped')
>>> print(x.sort())
None
```

Since `None == None` is always True, the function always returns True.

Further, the code can be simplified:

```
def are_anagrams(word1, word2):
    return sorted(word1) == sorted(word2)
```

Sample runs:

```
>>> are_anagrams("lopped", "poodle")
False
>>> are_anagrams("lopped", "doppel")
True
```

Notes:

1. Both `sort` and `sorted` operate on strings as well as lists.  There is no need to convert to lists first.
2. `sorted(word1) == sorted(word2)` evaluates to True or False.  Consequentl, the `if-then-else` statement can be eliminated.

#### Extensions to phrases and mixed-case

Phrases can also be considered anagrams of each other.  Also, for anagrams, case should generally be ignored.  Thus:

```
def are_anagrams(word1, word2):
    return sorted(word1.lower().replace(' ', '')) == sorted(word2.lower().replace(' ', ''))
```

Thus:

```
>>> are_anagrams('Lopped', 'Ed Plop')
True
```

#### Rejecting the case of words being equal

If the words are the same, should they be considered anagrams?  If not, then use:

```
     def are_anagrams(word1, word2):
        return (word1.lower() != word2.lower()) and sorted(word1.lower().replace(' ', '')) == sorted(word2.lower().replace(' ', ''))
```

Example:

```
>>> are_anagrams('Lopped', 'Lopped')
False
>>> are_anagrams('Lopped', 'Old Pep')
True
```

Comment: This function won't cater for words with spaces in them e.g. `are_anagrams('anagram', 'nag a ram')`. You can remove white spaces to handle this :)

Comment: @evans_murithi Good point: phrases can be anagrams.  Answer updated.  While I was at it, I also made it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the issue: `wordlist.sort()` will return `None` because it does the sorting **in place** comparing `None` to `None` will always evaluate to `True` and yield falsified results. You should be using `sorted()` which instead returns the newly sorted list and then perform the comparison:

```
def are_anagrams(word1, word2):
    word1list = list(word1)
    word2list = list(word2)
    anagramfalse = False
    anagramtrue = True
    if (word1 == word2):
        return anagramfalse
    if (sorted(word1list)) == (sorted(word2list)):
        return anagramtrue
    else:
        return anagramfalse
```

Apart from that, there are further things to note, first, no need to set explicit names for `True` and `False`; just return them:

```
def are_anagrams(word1, word2):
    word1list = list(word1)
    word2list = list(word2)
    if (word1 == word2):
        return False
    if (sorted(word1list)) == (sorted(word2list)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Second off, no need to cast the strings to lists with `list`, `sorted` will take care of that for you automatically by creating a `list` from the string, sorting it and then returning it:

```
def are_anagrams(word1, word2):
    if (word1 == word2):
        return False
    if (sorted(word1)) == (sorted(word2)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Third off `word1 == word2` won't really do much as a "quick check" to exit early; sorting is **fast** in general, you could drop that all together:

```
def are_anagrams(word1, word2):
    if (sorted(word1)) == (sorted(word2)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

For the final step to make this code as sortest as possible, look at Johns answer; he simply returns the result of comparing the sorted objects. No need to be explicit if your comparison will yield the right value for you. :-)

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot for that. Heaps to learn.

Although I think I still need the 

`if (word1 == word2):
        return False`

for the function, otherwise it will consider "poodle" and "poodle" anagrams, which technically are not. Correct?